# laptop internal speakers work but not external

Tags: windows-vista, speakers

Hello I have a toshiba satellite laptop and the external speakers do not work no matter which speakers I attach none of them will have sound however all of the external speakers work when I plug them into other machines.  My interal speakers are functioning fine.  What could be causing this issue maybe a window update or something else.  I am not too familiar with audo settings and how they effect the speaker output.

Answer (score 0):

After you plug them in you may have to change the default output device. This can be done in Control Panel under the "Audio Devices" section.

You will see a list of installed devices which allows you to change the default output device:

[image]

Some applications also need to be closed and reopened when a new sound device is selected. I know this is the case when using flash in web browsers on my machine.

Comment: what program is that? It looks similar, but not the native Windows one? :S