# internal speakers working but external speakers no sound

Tags: windows-vista, audio, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [laptop internal speakers work but not external](https://superuser.com/questions/187547/laptop-internal-speakers-work-but-not-external)

Hello,

I have a Toshiba laptop running windows vista.  Whenever I plug in external speakers the sound does not work.  THe internal speaker sound works  perfectly.  What could be blocking the external speakers from working?

Comment: This is an EXACT dupe. Please post questions only once.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I thought the yellow triangle was the sound card but it was something else.  It turns out the headset needed to be set to the default output device for the speakers to work.

Answer (score -1):

First the obvious question - Are they plugged in / can you confirm they are working?

I would try to plug them in to a MP3 player or alternatively try plugging in known working headphones in to the laptop in order to diagnose this problem.

Next, try to look in the sound properties (Right click `Volume / Speaker` icon on taskbar and choose `Playback devices`) and make sure that the external sound port is set up correctly and not muted / disabled or anything silly like that.

[image]

If you are still having problems, please say and I will try to help further.

Comment: Also on the obvious side, make sure the speakers have power and are turned on.

Comment: Yes these speakers are working and I have tried other speakers on this laptop with the same result of the speakers work on other computers but not this laptop.  I did see when I went into computer and devices it was showing a yellow triangle so I thought let me uninstall and reinstall the driver because when I selected update drive it gave a message that the drive was up to date even though I saw a yellow triangle.  THe name of this is ADS INSTANT HDTV PC.

Comment: Also I only have a port with a picture of microphone and a picture of headsets.  Should this laptop have a port with picture for speakers or is the speakers for this laptop can only be usb connection possibly. One thing is when I plug this green speaker connection to the port with the microphone picture next to it I hear a pop from the speakers. This is not my laptop but the owner says this used to work with external speakers before.

Comment: This is the error I saw prior to hitting unistall had a yellow triangle with an exclamation point indicating a code 10 error now I cant figure out how to reinstall it.

Comment: Ok - take a look at the manufacturers website and see if they have an updated audio driver package. It should be easy to install, but happy to help you if you get stuck. Sounds like the audio driver is not properly configured. (if yellow triangle was on the sound card.)